# github actions to kubernetes bare metal deployment

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a git repo of node, mongo

- wanted to setup ci cd on bare metal
- whenever here is a commit/mearge to a branch
- want to rebuild image
- run test cases (a node.js script)
- and notify

Not clear how to setup git hub actions on bare metals

Answer (score 1):

What you need can be achieved with this [Github Action for Kubernetes CLI](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/kubernetes-cli-kubectl). You just need to set your kubernetes config file in your project secrets.